# How do you use the Bounded typeclass in Haskell to define a type with a floating point range?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I expected the following code to fail with a type error due to violation of the minBound and maxBound. But, as you can see, it goes through without flagging an error.

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -XTypeSynonymInstances #-}
module Main where

type Probability = Float
instance Bounded Probability where
    minBound = 0.0
    maxBound = 1.0

testout :: Float -> Probability
testout xx = xx + 1.0

main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ testout 0.5
  putStrLn $ show $ testout (-1.5)
  putStrLn $ show $ testout 1.5
```

In the Prelude I get this

```
*Main> :type (testout 0.5)
(testout 0.5) :: Probability
```

And at the prompt I get this:

```
[~/test]$runhaskell demo.hs
1.5
-0.5
2.5
```

Clearly I'm not declaring Bounded properly, and I'm sure I'm doing something wrong syntactically.  There isn't much simple stuff on Google regarding Bounded typeclasses, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's not what `Bounded` is for. `Bounded a` just defines the functions `minBound :: a` and `maxBound :: a`.  It does not induce any special checking or anything.

You can define a bounded type using a so-called *smart constructor*.  That is:

```
module Probability (Probability) where

newtype Probability = P { getP :: Float }
    deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

mkP :: Float -> Probability
mkP x | 0 <= x && x <= 1 = P x
      | otherwise = error $ show x ++ " is not in [0,1]"

-- after this point, the Probability data constructor is not to be used

instance Num Probability where
    P x + P y = mkP (x + y)
    P x * P y = mkP (x * y)
    fromIntegral = mkP . fromIntegral
    ...
```

So the only way to make a `Probability` is to use the `mkP` function eventually (this is done for you when you use numeric operations given our `Num` instance), which checks that the argument is in range.  Because of the module's export list, outside of this module is it not possible to construct an invalid probability.

Probably not the two-liner you were looking for, but oh well.

For extra composability, you could factor out this functionality by making a `BoundCheck` module instead of `Probability`.  Just like above, except:

```
newtype BoundCheck a = BC { getBC :: a }
    deriving (Bounded,Eq,Ord,Show)

mkBC :: (Bounded a) => a -> BoundCheck a
mkBC x | minBound <= x && x <= maxBound = BC x
       | otherwise = error "..."

instance (Bounded a) => Num (BoundCheck a) where
    BC x + BC y = mkBC (x + y)
    ...
```

Thus you can get the functionality you were wishing was built in for you when you asked the question.

To do this deriving stuff you may need the language extension `{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}`.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you very much. One question: you put an ellipses ("...") for defining the various ways in which mkP and mkBC interact with existing operators on things of Num type. I suppose the purpose of that is to define arithmetic operators for things of Probability type which keep running the output through mkP to do bounds checking.

Comment: In case you don't know where to look for the `Num` methods: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.2.0.2/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3ANum

Comment: Is Probability actually a number?  Its true that the underlying representation is, and you have to do arithmetic operations on that underlying representation to evaluate the results of a probability expression.  But the actual operations on Probability are going to be (con/dis)junction and inversion.