# What is the optimal way of representing a floating point number in a range from 0 to 1?

Tags: haskell, types, floating-point, numbers

I'm looking for a numeric type able to represent, say, a value `0.213123` or `0.0`, or `1.0`, but refusing the out of range values, such as `-0.2123` and `1.2312`. Does there exist a specific type fitting that purpose, and what is the optimal general approach to restricting numbers to a specific range?

Of course, the first answer coming to mind is: just use `Double`, but getting spoiled by Haskell's type system I've gotten used to maximally securing the program on a type level.

Comment: You mentioned Haskell- is that the language you are asking about?

Comment: @TTT On SO it's conventional for the language reference to be implied by the associated tags. So, yes.

Comment: Have you looked at this (it doesn't give you static type checking, but outside of the defining module, it's not possible to have an invalid value)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557394/how-do-you-use-the-bounded-typeclass-in-haskell-to-define-a-type-with-a-floating

Comment: What operations does this datatype need to support?

Comment: @dave4420 Let's assume none

Comment: @NikitaVolkov If you don't need to support any operations then `data NumberBetweenZeroAndOne = NumberBetweenZeroAndOne` supports all the functionality you need, and without the overhead of actually storing a number from [0,1] to boot. But presumably this is inadequate for your purposes. What operations do you need this datatype to support?

Comment: By "optimal", do you mean "idiomatic", or are you actually interested in maximizing precision while minimizing overhead?

Comment: This sounds like something called "binary angles" which is just fixed point math using only fractional bits.

Comment: @dave4420 Basically all I need is convertion to and from Double.

Comment: @DanBurton Idiomatic and performant, the precision is not an issue at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A Serious Suggestions**

You could use a newtype wrapper (and  smart constructor) around a word of the proper bit size:

```
newtype SmallFrac = SF Word64

-- Example conversion (You'd actually want to make
-- instances of common classes, I assume)
sfToDouble :: SmallFrac -> Double
sfToDouble (SF x) = fromIntegral x / fromIntegral (maxBound `asTypeOf` x)

instance Show SmallFrac where
    show = show . sfToDouble
```

Implementing multiplication and division might be more costly than you would like, but at least addition is easy (modulo protecting against over/underflow) and you claim to not need any operations so even better.

**A Less Useful Suggestion**

If all you need is a symbol representing a value exists between one and zero then take dave4420's suggestion and just have a unit type:

```
newtype SmallFrac = SF ()
```

There are no operations for this type, not even conversion to/from other types of interest such as `Double`, but this meets the request as stated.

Comment: Your less useful suggestion hints at a very important idea for designing data representations.  The first time I was exposed to this idea explicitly was in [an article](http://math.andrej.com/2008/02/06/representations-of-uncomputable-and-uncountable-sets/) by Andrej Bauer.

Comment: Agreed! I was meaning symbolic representation is probably less useful for the asker's specific problem, not that it is useless in general.

Comment: I really like your "Serious" suggestion. Of all the answers it is the only approaching the issue on the type level. I however totally don't get how the "Less Useful Suggestion" can be used. Can you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: Notice the "serious" answer is just a fixed point type where there are zero non-fractional bits.  I never tested such a corner case, but you might be able to use my `fixedpoint-simple` package and generate a type `FixedPoint_0_64` with all the useful classes using the template haskell macro `mkFixedPoint`.

Answer (score 4):

Not standard.  You'd have to make one -- I'd suggest a [smart constructor](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors).   Keep in mind though that such a type supports very few numeric operations -- you can't add them and keep them in the set, nor negate them, so I would advise against a `Num` instance.  A `Monoid` on multiplication would be reasonable.

Comment: This will also be a dynamic check, which unfortunately defeats the purpose. Also this will result in quite unreasonable overhead on every instantiation.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov, then you are out of luck.  Haskell lacks the capabilities to know detailed information about values at compile type. Cf. Idris, Agda, Coq.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Why is the smart constructor "unreasonable overhead"? Do you really believe it will cause a performance issue, or is it simply academic and it "feels" like there should be a more efficient way?

Answer (score 3):

### Representation based on Double

```
newtype Rep1 = Rep1 Double

checkRange :: Double -> Maybe Double
checkRange x
  | 0 < x && x < 1 = Just x
  | otherwise = Nothing

toRep1 :: Double -> Maybe Rep1
toRep1 x = Rep1 . (\x -> tan $ (x-0.5) * pi) <$> checkRange x

fromRep1 :: Rep1 -> Double
fromRep1 (Rep1 x) = atan x / pi + 0.5
```

### Representation based on Integers

```
data Rep2 = Rep2 Integer Integer

fromRep2 :: Rep2 -> Double
fromRep2 (Rep2 a b) = fromIntegral (abs a) / fromIntegral (abs a + abs b + 1)

toRep2 :: Double -> Maybe Rep2
toRep2 = error "left to the reader"
```

Comment: These are just examples, of course — there are many more possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

A variation on the smart constructor pattern.

This may be overkill.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Foo (Foo(), doubleFromFoo,
            maybeFooFromDouble, unsafeFooFromDouble, thFooFromDouble)
where
import Language.Haskell.TH
```

Anyway, standard `newtype`...

```
newtype Foo = Foo Double
```

Getting a `Double` out is easy...

```
doubleFromFoo :: Foo -> Double
doubleFromFoo (Foo x) = x
```

Putting a `Double` in at runtime incurs a runtime check, no getting round that...

```
maybeFooFromDouble :: Double -> Maybe Foo
maybeFooFromDouble x
        | 0 <= x && x <= 1 = Just (Foo x)
        | otherwise        = Nothing
```

...unless you're happy being unsafe (and have some social means of enforcing that all uses of `unsafeFooFromDouble` are actually safe)...

```
unsafeFooFromDouble :: Double -> Foo
unsafeFooFromDouble = Foo
```

But if it's a compile-time constant, you can do the check at compile-time, with no runtime overhead:

```
thFooFromDouble :: (Real a, Show a) => a -> Q Exp
thFooFromDouble x
        | 0 <= x && x <= 1 = return $ AppE (VarE 'unsafeFooFromDouble)
                                           (LitE (RationalL (toRational x)))
        | otherwise        = fail $ show x ++ " is not between 0 and 1"
```

And this is how you use that last function:

```
$(thFooFromDouble 0.3)
```

Remember not to put any spaces between the `$` and the `(`!.

Comment: Oh bother. This isn't going to work is it? The data constructor isn't available in the client code, so the code generated by `thFooFromDouble` can't use it. I suppose if you exported `unsafeFooFromDouble` you could use that in the generated code, which would be better than exporting the data constructor directly. Then you have to grep your code for `unsafe` and ensure any uses of `unsafeFooFromDouble` have a comment justifying why they're safe, but you should perhaps be doing that for `unsafePerformIO` etc anyway. Yes, I'm going to go with that.

Comment: This is false -- if you use quotation syntax in your TH macro (i.e: 'Foo) rather than construct a string name (i.e: mkName "Foo") then you get early binding of the name. It is hygienic and need not be exported.