# How does Bounded typeclass works for custom datatype?

Tags: haskell

For Int8, the bounded range is

```
minBound :: Int8 -- -128
maxBound :: Int8 -- 127
```

If I add two Int8 integers

```
(127 :: Int8) + (10 :: Int8) --  -119
```

Why does it not show out of bound error instead?

If I create a datatype and add an instance of Bounded:

```
newtype Boost = Boost Int
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Num Boost where
    (Boost a) + (Boost b) = Boost (a+b)

instance Bounded Boost where
    minBound = Boost 1
    maxBound = Boost 10

(Boost 10) + (Boost 12) -- Boost 22
```

Clearly it did not behave like the Int8, So how can I make a bounded instance for my custom datatype?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use the Bounded typeclass in Haskell to define a type with a floating point range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557394/how-do-you-use-the-bounded-typeclass-in-haskell-to-define-a-type-with-a-floating)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Bounded` does not affect arithmetical operations, it only provides for two constants `minBound, maxBound`. Whoever writes the `Bounded` instance is expected to define there the bounds for the values which can be represented inside the type.

If you want to restrict arithmetics with an error, define your own `Num` instance.

```
instance Num Boost where
   (Boost a) + (Boost b) | 0 <= a+b && a+b < 8 = Boost (a+b)
                         | otherwise = error "out of range"
   -- other operations here
```

Comment: This make sense, also why does adding `(127 :: Int8) + (10 :: Int8)` results in negative value?

Comment: @jyet Because of overflow: `Int8` goes from -128 to 127. When you compute 127+1 you get -128. Basically, 256 is added/subtracted to the result as many times as needed to fit in the range. This happens with any fixed-bound integer type, in almost any programming language.